# Show Login Screen for iPhone when app becomes active

Tags: xcode

From other threads here I have gotten a modal view "login screen" to show whenever my app starts for the first time. What I want now is to have the login screen show whenever the app is brought back into the foreground (i.e. its running in the background and is brought up again) so the user can log back in.

Here's my code from the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];


    if (lockScreenOnOff) 
    {
        [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

where the modal login view is shown if a switch (lockScreenOnOff) is on. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` in your application delegate. ([UIApplicationDelegate class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive%3a))

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create all view controllers

    [self lockApplicationAnimated:NO]; // Lock on launching
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)lockApplicationAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:self.loginViewController
                                             animated:animated];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Lock the application
    // Also, save all user data because the application might terminate soon
    [self lockApplicationAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Hooray, the user returned!
    // Screen should be locked because the applicationDidEnterBackground
}
```

Additionally you can also use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to invalidate a session after a certain amount of time.

Comment: I tried this by adding the same code I posted originally in both of these places. The lock screen does come up again (like I hoped it would), but if you hit the home button then re-enter the app, the modal screen goes away (defeating the lock screen).

Comment: You need to call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` only once, in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Try to present the modalViewController only when `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Comment: You are a genius, no lie. Seriously thank you for the help, been trying to get that solved for a while now!